# How do I remove all possible extraneous spaces, tabs, next line, and others from an input to clean up a stdin python input?

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have tried the following code in different variations with no avail. The user may input unstructured data like so

`"4231, 312  1231212,12 1 23 123,12,3,123 123   1,2,      3123"` ,

and i am trying to clean it up to

`[4231, 312, 1231212, 12, 1, 23, 123, 12 , 3, 123, 123, 1, 2, 3123]`

Code:

```
print("Please enter the numbers (separated by space, comma or
    line) then press CMD/CTRL D :")
num_input = sys.stdin.read()

def convert_number_input(integer_inputs):
"""Takes integer inputs separated by comma or space or line as a string and converts to list of operable integers.
First checks for comma typos in input, then removes spaces and irrelevant data, then finally converts to integer.
If just one number is the input it simply converts it to integer list"""

first_input = re.sub(r"[\n\t\s]", " ", integer_inputs)

all_comma_input = first_input.strip()

stripping_input = all_comma_input.replace(' ', ',')

fresh_input = stripping_input.strip(',')

clean_integer_inputs = fresh_input.replace(',,,', ',')

very_clean_integer_inputs = clean_integer_inputs.replace(',,', ',')

split_input = very_clean_integer_inputs.split(',')

final_input = list(map(int, split_input))

return final_input

final_num_input = convert_num_input(num_input)

print(final_num_input)
```

Comment: you might want to wrap your end command on a try/catch if you will convert these numbers to integers (or float).  Users might make mistakes and type non-numeric characters and the conversion would break your program.

Comment: JAponte how would you recommend I do that?

Comment: It depends.  How do you want to handle typos?  Will the program just exit, or will it request for the input again?

Comment: I posted an answer below.  Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `re.findall` can absolutely do the trick.  But if you want to be extra careful and user-friendly, you might want to define a strategy to handle bad input.  For instance, such strategy could be to give the user several attempts to input the data.  Here is a full reproducible example:

```
import sys
import re


def convert_number_input(x):
    faulty_input = re.findall(r"[^0-9^,^\s^\n]", x)
    if faulty_input:
        raise Exception("Certain characters in your input are not quite welcomed...\n" + ','.join(faulty_input))
    return re.findall(r"\d+", x)

def run(raw_text=None):
    print("Please enter the numbers (separated by space, comma or line) then press CMD/CTRL D :")

    count = 0
    while count < 3:
        try:
            if not raw_text:
                raw_text = sys.stdin.read()
            clean_inputs = convert_number_input(raw_text)
            print("Your numeric inputs were:\n%s" % ', '.join(clean_inputs))
            exit(0)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.message)
            count += 1

    print("Sorry... your input is pretty bad.  I'll just stop here and quietly cry.")
    exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Erroneous input example
    my_input = "j4231, 312  1231212,12 1 23 123,12,3,123 123   1,2,      3123"
    run(my_input)

    # Good input
    my_input = "4231, 312  1231212,12 1 23 123,12,3,123 123   1,2,      3123"
    run(my_input)
```

Comment: @tosin, You're welcome. Do you mind voting and/or accepting a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Guess you can use `list comprehension` to that

```
>>> [int(z.strip()) for z in x.replace(',', " ").split(' ') if z.strip()]

[4231, 312, 1231212, 12, 1, 23, 123, 12, 3, 123, 123, 1, 2, 3123]
```

or , if want `regex`, use `\s+`

```
>>> list(map(int, re.split(r'\s+', x.replace(',',''))))

[4231, 312, 123121212, 1, 23, 123123123, 123, 12, 3123]
```

Comment: Although this answer is on the right track, it doesn't provide the expected results.  For instance, if we remove commas at the beginning, there is the chance of joining two numbers entered as "123,456", which would result in "123456".

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
re.split(r'[\t, \n]+', string)
```

The code will split the string if there is one or more `tab(\t)`, `space( )` or `line break(\n)` in the string.
Attention, if there is break in the head or tail of the string, a extra `""` element will be add into the list. You can use `string.strip()` to delete the `""` element.

Comment: Add small explanation even though code is explanatory

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module:

```
import re

s = "4231, 312  1231212,12 1 23 123,12,3,123 123   1,2,      3123"

cleaned_list = [int(i) for i in re.findall('\d+', s)]
print(cleaned_list)
```

Will print:

```
[4231, 312, 1231212, 12, 1, 23, 123, 12, 3, 123, 123, 1, 2, 3123]
```